# PHP mysql query insert where

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to confirm a users email where the users verification key is the variable `$verify_mod`. However, I get the error,

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE verification='72b4ad7ee82dd6e177f2588c168abb51user=test123'' at line 1

Here's my query:

```
$confirm_query = "INSERT INTO users (confirm_email) VALUES ('1') WHERE verification='$verify_mod'";
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The INSERT statement doesn't go with a WHERE clause. Either you're trying to insert something, in which case you should remove the WHERE clause, or you want to *modify* a value, in which case you should use UPDATE .. SET.

```
// For an insert:
$confirm_query = "INSERT INTO users (confirm_email) VALUES ('1')";
// For an update:
$confirm_query = "UPDATE users SET confirm_email='1' WHERE verification='$verify_mod'";
```

Besides that, it's always a good idea to put ` characters around table and column names to reduce the risk of SQL injection. So:

```
// For an insert:
$confirm_query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`confirm_email`) VALUES ('1')";
// For an update:
$confirm_query = "UPDATE `users` SET `confirm_email`='1' WHERE `verification`='$verify_mod'";
```

Lastly, I don't know if you're using mysqli_* functions or PDO or mysql_* functions (in the latter case you should definitely change to one of the others as mysql_* is deprecated). In any of the first two cases you should use parameterized queries or [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). You prepare the query and then fill in the variables (`$verify_mod` here). That way, the variables get escaped properly, again, to reduce the risk of SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an insert, this sounds like it should be an update statement though (you can't do where in inserts either as it doesn't make sense to):

```
$confirm_query = "UPDATE users set confirm_email=1 WHERE verification='$verify_mod'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending upon @CamilStaps answer, here's how you can parameterize your query using mysqli.

```
// For an insert: (No need to bind parameters for this one)
$confirm_query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`confirm_email`) VALUES ('1')");
$confirm_query->execute();
// For an update:
$confirm_query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `confirm_email`='1' WHERE `verification`= ? ");
$confirm_query->bind_param('s', $verify_mod); 
$confirm_query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, i searched all over google trying to find how to do that